# Reading a binary file with fread

Tags: c, fread, bin

I am trying to read a bin with `fread`? . The binary file I am reading has 1 million sets of data. However I am only getting 600+ and the data read is either `0` or `-1.#QNAN0`. Am I using `fread` the right way?

```
struct Data {
    float time;
    float signal1;
    float signal2;
    float signal3;
};

long i;
static struct Data data[1000]; //(Solve by using static)

long openfile() {

  FILE *fp;
  char* filename = "Test_0012.bin";

  fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (fp == NULL){
      printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
      return 1;
  }

  while(!feof(fp)){
    fread(&data, sizeof(data),1,fp);

    printf("%d\t", i);
    printf("%f\t", data[i].time);
    printf("%f\t", data[i].signal1);
    printf("%f\t", data[i].signal2);
    printf("%f\n", data[i].signal3);

    i++;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Is the result of `fread` equal to `sizeof(data)`?

Comment: If the file contains a million data sets, then an array of 1000 items isn't going to be large enough to store this data.

Comment: BTW: it's probably not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong), there may be other unrelated problems

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
  fread(&data[i], sizeof(struct Data), 1, fp);
} while (!feof(fp));
```

You want to read n times the size of `struct Data`, rather than once the whole array.

BTW you also need to check if there are no  more than 1000 (which equals `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])` entries, and you need to check if the value returned by `fread` is the same as the number of elements you asked to read (1 in this case), otherwise a read error has occurred.

But there could also be a problem with the binary file itself, depending on how it has been generated. It would be helpful to see that code.

Comment: still `while (!feof(fp));` is not completely correct. It doesn't cover read errors

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt explanations added